# Activate emmet in Atom.io

Tags: emmet, atom-editor

I am using a fresh new installation of the atom editor and I just installed emmet.

But when I type e.g.:

```
div.abcde
```

and press TAB, nothing happen.

Did I forgot something to activate?

[image]

Comment: Make sure you’ve set your document syntax to HTML: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom#tab-key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to **restart the atom editor** to work with Emmet or any other package. this will help you .

Answer (score 18):

In atom 1.3.1(might work for older versions, im pretty sure)

1.Simply press

```
ctrl+shift+L
```

or in the Menu : Edit -> Select Grammar.

2.Make sure you select the right Grammar, for example : HTML in your case. I just found out this was my problem, now its working perfectly fine.

Comment: I had my type as "HTML (Angular)", when I switched to just "HTML", Emmet started working.

Comment: I too had my type as "HTML (Angular)", when I switched to just "HTML", Emmet started working. Thanks for quick tip.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, sir! Works like a charm!

Comment: glad i could help! This should probably be the accepted answer :P

Comment: perfect. This did the trick, as it asked me to select the grammar, otherwise it wasn't able to detect the type of the file at first. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In windows it works for me using ctrl+e;

I typed **div.alert.alert-success** at last I press ctrl+e then it gives me

```
 <div class="alert alert-success"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem - it was because HTML (Angular) was set as default language validator for html files. Changed it to just "HTML" and it works as a charm!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Atom
2. Option File -> Keymap ----> and paste at the end.

   ```
   'atom-text-editor:not([mini])': 'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
   ```
3. Save and ok.
4. Restart Atom and ready, `Tab` returns to work with Emmet

Comment: This worked for me - upvoted! Thank you. Didn't need to change the Grammar or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Press

```
ctrl + alt + enter
```

go to Expand Abbreviation (interactive) mode
and Commit your Command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Example, `div.col-md-12`  Then simply enter TAB(default key)
2. If it does not work the open **File->Keymap->** then paste this

> 'atom-text-editor:not([mini])': 'tab':
>   'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'

and save it.

Answer (score 0):

The new emmet version may have easier access to the boilerplate code.

So when typing html without abbreviating just **press enter instead of tab**, followed by the html. This has worked for me.